# Why this SQL statement is wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Given the table below -called marks- why the following statement is wrong?

```
SELECT student_name, SUM(subject1)
FROM marks
WHERE student_name LIKE 'R%';
```

Following is 'marks' table
[image]

Comment: It should provide you an error message.

Comment: Poor title. Summarize your specific technical problem.

Comment: What is the meaning of `SUBJECT1`? Is it the grade a student has received in a specific "subject"? If so, then what is the meaning of `SUM(SUBJECT1)`? Sum calculated separately for each student? Or for all students whose name begins with R? And if it's separately for each student, why does a student even have more than **one** grade in any given subject? And if some students may have more than one grade in a single subject, how is the SUM of those grades **ever** relevant to anything in real life? Why not MAX, or AVG? Note - these questions are about the problem itself, not the code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a **GROUP BY** whenever we perform an aggregation function like SUM, AVG.. etc.

> SELECT student_name,SUM(subject1) 
>   FROM marks
>   WHERE student_name
>   LIKE'R%' GROUP BY student_name;

Hope this works for you now!

Answer (score 0):

Why is it wrong?

The `SUM()` makes this an aggregation query.  An aggregation query is fine without a `GROUP BY`.  It returns one row and *all* columns in the `SELECT` should be aggregation functions.

However, you have an unaggregated column `student_name`.  This is not in a `GROUP BY` and it is not the argument to an aggregation function.

Presumably, you want `GROUP BY student_name`.  But there are other possibilities, such as `MIN()`, `MAX()` or `LISTAGG()`.